# jQuery Animation not working in IE9 & Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here's the source, am I missing something?
I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CcuWR/), and it works, but on my PC it's not working.
--EDIT
I used jquery min v1.4.1, it didn't work, so I downloaded latest version, still not working, on the link I used google's jquery SDN which is v1.5.1.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#bio > div').hide();
        $('#bio > div:first').show();
    });
    $('#bio h3').click(function() {
        alert('called');
        $(this).next().animate(
            {'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'swing'
        );
    });
    $('p:first').animate(
        {
        height: '+=100px',
        backgroundColor: 'green'
        },
        {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'swing',
            complete: function() {alert('done!');},
            queue: false
        }
    );
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="bio">
            <h2>Who’s Hot Right Now?</h2>
            <h3>Beau Dandy</h3>
            <div>
                <img src="../images/beau_100.jpg" width="100"
                    height="100" alt="Beau Dandy"/>
                <p>Content about Beau Dandy</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Johnny Stardust</h3>
            <div>
                <img src="../images/johnny_100.jpg" width="100"
                height="100" alt="Johny Stardust"/>
                <p>Content about Johny Stardust</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Glendatronix</h3>
            <div>
                <img src="../images/glenda_100.jpg" width="100"
                    height="100" alt="Glendatronix"/>
                <p>Content about Glendatronix</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define "not working" in great detail.

Comment: Toggling is not animated. When I click headers nothing toggles. None of jqueries mentioning animate work.

Comment: @Marc, by here you mean on jsfiddle? If so, yes I mentioned that. It's not working on my PC nor my laptop. What could I have gotten wrong?|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `document.ready` was being closed too soon.

I simply moved the brackets  `});` to the end of your script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#bio > div').hide();
    $('#bio > div:first').show();
    $('#bio h3').click(function() {
        alert('called');
        $(this).next().animate(
            {'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'swing'
        );
    });
    $('p:first').animate(
        {
        height: '+=100px',
        backgroundColor: 'green'
        },
        {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'swing',
        complete: function() {alert('done!');},
        queue: false
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Why?  For example, you're trying to bind events like `.click()` to an element called `#bio h3`.  However, the element `#bio h3` might not yet even exist yet in the DOM since you're calling the script in the `<head>`.  Using `document.ready` ensures the DOM exists before executing the code within.

Why it works in some browsers is likely a simple timing issue.

Comment: Thanks, now I get the alert saying it was called but wouldn't show/hide divs.

Comment: This should solve the problem. You need to define events etc. inside $('document').ready(function() {}); or $(function() {}); aswell

Comment: Works fine in FF, but not in IE. Isn't jQuery supposed to be portable?

Comment: Mostly, yes. Sometimes new browsers or versions comes with new settings which may render it unstable and gets resolved in newer versions. Try changing "the show()" to either: $('#bio > div:first-child').show(); or $('#bio > div').eq(0).show();

Comment: Still not working, the content is not rendered completely. just shows a line instead of the image, and the text is not show. But still, thanks for your help.